# Is there one MBR for all partitions on a HDD?

Tags: windows-7, mbr

It seems that there is one MBR per physical Disk Drive.  I.e., if your MBR on the drive is corrupt then all of the partitions are affected.  And before trying to fix the MBR, I should backup the whole drive, right?

Comment: *It seems that there is one MBR per physical Disk Drive.* ... until the drive is included in a RAID. *before trying to fix the MBR, I should backup the whole drive, right?* It depends of the fix type/method. In some cases it's enough to make copy of MBR only, in some cases it's enough to make copy of all sectors in the partition chain, sometimes you need additionally to make a copy of segments/volumes bootblocks. But to have the copy of whole HDD is the best choice. The only problems - you must have another HDD with proper size, and the copying maybe time-expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Each partition/volume on a disk has an individual [VBR](https://wiki.osdev.org/Volume_Boot_Record). The MBR is for the whole disk.

By default there is no backup of the MBR on the disk. If you're attempting to recover the MBR of a disk it's likely a good idea to get a complete image of it first.